# C++ template "is not a type" error

Tags: c++, templates

I have two templated classes. CCData and CCNode. The second (CCNode) declares two instances of the first (CCData) as part of its protected set of variables.

In the cc_data.tpl.h file we have

```
template<class T>
 class CCData
 {

 public:

  // Constructor. Allocates memory for the values. Initialise them to
  // zero
  CCData(const unsigned n_values, const unsigned n_history_values=1);

  .
  .
  .
  .

 };
```

And in the cc_node.tpl.h file we have

```
template<class T, class DIM>
  class CCNode
 {

 public:

  // Constructor
  CCNode(const unsigned n_variables, const unsigned n_history_values);

  .
  .
  .
  .

 protected:

  // The number of variables stored in the node
  const unsigned N_variables;

  // The number of history values of the variable stored in the node
  const unsigned N_history_values;

  // Store the spatial position of the node
  CCData<double> X(DIM, N_history_values);

  // Store the values of the variables stored in the node
  CCData<T> U(N_variables, N_history_values);

 };
```

The cc_node.tpl.cpp file

```
template<class T, class DIM>
CCNode<T,DIM>::CCNode(const unsigned n_variables, const unsigned n_history_values)
 : N_variables(n_variables), N_history_values(n_history_values)
{ }
```

The problematic lines are in the cc_node.tpl.h file

```
  // Store the spatial position of the node
  CCData<double> X(DIM, N_history_values);

  // Store the values of the variables stored in the node
  CCData<T> U(N_variables, N_history_values);
```

where the compiler barks with

```
cc_node.tpl.h:90:25: error: ‘N_history_values’ is not a type
cc_node.tpl.h:92:15: error: ‘N_variables’ is not a type
cc_node.tpl.h:92:28: error: ‘N_history_values’ is not a type
```

My gcc version

```
gcc version 5.4.0
```

with no fancy compilation flags other than

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -O0 -g ...
```

Comment: What values do you expect `N_history_values` and `N_variables` to have? You haven't initialized them anywhere.

Comment: They are initialised in the constructor of the CCNode class. Please check edit.

Comment: You're calling `CCData<T> U(N_variables, N_history_values)`, but `N_variables` and `N_history_values` are never initialized to actual unsigned values.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `CCData<double> X(DIM, N_history_values);`? It looks like a function definition, which is why the compiler is expecting a type.

Comment: Line `CCData<double> X(DIM, N_history_values);` doesn't make any sense. `DIM` is a type, 'N_history_values' is a value. May be you mean `template<class T, int DIM>`? Then you should initialize `CCData<double> X = { DIM, N_history_values };`

Comment: @bejado Now I am confused, I can not see why I need to initialise the `_history_values` and `N_variables` in the class definition. I am initialising them in the constructor in the `cc_node.tpl.cpp` file. Once  I create a `CCNode` object I will certainly give actual `unsigned` values to the constructor e.g. `CCNode<double, 3> my_node(1, 1)`.

Comment: @TheDark Yep, you are right, it certainly looks like a function definition, and I guess that is why the compiler cries with the `is not a type` error.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko You are right, `DIM` should be an integer value (I prefer an `unsigned` in this case). I have seen that kind of initialisation `CCData<double> X = { DIM, N_history_values };` only in C11 references thus I would require to add the compilation flag `-std=c11` right?

Comment: @PePeLoTe: default member initializer is c++11 feature anyway. Is c++98 you must put initialization to a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing that you forgot is you passed a Type Name(DIM) as constructor arguments but constructor parameter should be value not a type name.
another problem is you defined a template function (constructor) in a .cpp file . but you should define all template functions inside same header file to use.
i Edited your code and it's works for me.

```
 template<class T>
 class CCData
 {

 public:

  // Constructor. Allocates memory for the values. Initialise them to
  // zero
  CCData(const unsigned n_values, const unsigned n_history_values=1)
  {

  }

 };

 template<class T, class DIM>
 class CCNode
 {

 public:

  // Constructor
  CCNode(const unsigned n_variables, const unsigned n_history_values):
      N_variables(n_variables),
      N_history_values(n_history_values),
      X(n_variables,n_history_values),// pass CCData constructor arguments
      U(n_variables,n_history_values)// pass CCData constructor arguments
      {}

 protected:

  // The number of variables stored in the node
  const unsigned N_variables;

  // The number of history values of the variable stored in the node
  const unsigned N_history_values;

  // Store the spatial position of the node
  CCData<double> X;//(DIM, N_history_values); -> DIM is a type name not a value

  // Store the values of the variables stored in the node
  CCData<T> U;//(N_variables, N_history_values);

 };
```

You must put Constructor definition in same header file. because compiler needs template function definition when compiling.

Comment: Yep, you are right, `DIM` is a type. It should read `template<class T, unsigned DIM>`. Because of that your solution is "partialy" right since for my specific case `DIM` must be passed as the first argument of the `X` object. It should read `X(DIM, n_history_values)`.

Comment: Regarding the header files for templates issue, I am using 3 files, a `*.tpl.h` files for the class definition, a `*.tpl.cpp` for the implementation of the class and a `*.h` file which only two lines are `#include "cc_node.tpl.h"` and `#include "cc_node.tpl.cpp"`. This way you "trick" the compiler such that the definition and the implementation are included in the `cc_node.h` file.